# Opposite of "to my credit"?

Tags: phrase-requests, antonyms

In writing a question for Stack Exchange, I wanted to write a sentence similar to "To my credit, I did foo, bar, and baz," except foo, bar, and baz are bad things so they are actually the opposite of being to my credit. What is a the opposite of the phrase "to my credit"?

Possibilities I considered:

- "That said..." - This is what I used, but it required me to rework my sentence somewhat.
- "Not to my credit..." - Awkward.
- "Against my credit..." - Might work, but I've never heard it used before.
- "To my debt..." - Takes the credit/debt metaphor too far.

Comment: _"However, I admit that"_, _"Having said that"_, _"On the flip side"_.

Comment: The answer could, potentially, be as easy as, "to spite my code, I barred my line."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An idiomatic phrase for this is “***to my shame***”. One might also say “***To my discredit***, I did ...”.  Alternately, consider “***Regrettably***”, “***Sadly***”, or “***Unfortunately***” in place of a “***To my ...*** phrase.  These latter three forms are more general and less personal, which is suitable unless you wish to place blame or credit on someone.  “***Regrettably***” seems like a good choice.

The rest of this answer considers, via Google Ngrams, historical incidence of “***To my ...*** phrases.  While ngram statistics are not gospel truth (due to confounding with out-of-context searched phrases) they are the most righteous data easily available.

A Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+my+detriment%2Cto+my+shame%2Cto+my+discredit&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for six phrases (see below) shows that *to my shame* has appeared in print 3 to 4 times more frequently than the next most frequent phrase.

The six phrases treated in the link above are *to my shame*, *to my detriment* and *to my discredit*, plus those phrases with *To* instead of *to*.

The Google [Ngrams picture](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+my+detriment%2CTo+my+detriment%2Cto+my+shame%2CTo+my+shame%2Cto+my+discredit%2CTo+my+discredit&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20my%20detriment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20my%20shame%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTo%20my%20shame%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20my%20discredit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTo%20my%20discredit%3B%2Cc0) shown below covers a shorter period than the first Ngrams link, making it easier to interpret.
[image: NGrams picture mentioned in text]

Another useful [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+detriment%2Cmy+shame%2Cmy+discredit%2Cmy+sorrow%2Cmy+chagrin&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20detriment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20shame%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20discredit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20sorrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20chagrin%3B%2Cc0) covers the phrases *my detriment, my shame, my discredit, my sorrow, my chagrin*.

Comment: "To my shame" carries a bit more of an emotional connotation that I was intending to convey, but it and "to my discredit" are both good suggestions. Unfortunately, it seems I can't upvote yet, sorry!

Comment: @Drake: Erm... I think in these contexts, *shame* is effectively the "opposite" to *credit*. It's not a matter of "emotional" connotations - simply *positive/negative*.

Comment: +1 for "to my discredit," which I like becase it explicitly name-checks the more common expression you're riffing on.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I disagree. To see this better, compare "to his credit" vs. "to his shame": "to his credit" means that I, the speaker, feel positively about what he did, whereas "to his shame" means that *he* feels ashamed of what he did.

Comment: @ruakh: Sure, if you introduce a second or third person into the equation, you can split hairs about who awards credit, or who feels shame. But OP is asking about *“to **my** credit”*, which IMHO normally refers to the pride ***I*** take in something I did, rather any positive feelings  anyone else might have about it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My point is that "to my shame" is emotional in a way that "to my credit" is not. I brought up the "his" in order to make this obvious. (But I like your idea that, in describing an emotion, it's "splitting hairs" to care about who's having the emotion. "Why are you still mad at me? I already *said* someone was sorry!")

Comment: Ngrams results may be misleading. "To my shame" will include "… added to my shame," "cut to my shame," "spoke to my shame," and other incidental uses. The other alternatives to "shame" are simply less generally common.

Comment: I'm not certain why "to my detriment" is so rare with the first person (perhaps the speaker is more concerned with his shame than the more overt but the less personal injuries detriment refers to?), but "to his detriment" is more common than "to his shame". ("To his chagrin" trumps both.)

Comment: Another phrase to add to these is "to my sorrow": http://goo.gl/8yUgzb Though, as @Potatoswatter observes, combinations with sorrow, shame, and chagrin have many more uses aside from what the OP is looking for, while "to my detriment" (my first choice) is mostly limited to the sense he requires.

Comment: @ruakh Shame doesn't just mean the feeling of shame, but also the thing felt: dishonor or disgrace. Fumblefingers is on to something when he says it is thus the opposite of credit. I still prefer "to my detriment" though.

Comment: @Vectornaut Yes! I had independently thought of using "to my discredit" to signal that I was inverting the conditions of the usual "to my credit". I just found this thread by googling for whether that inversion is in common usage.

Answer (score 20):

To my *chagrin*, which Merriam-Webster defines as

> **chagrin**
>
> a feeling of being frustrated or annoyed because of failure or disappointment

The Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+my+shame%2Cto+my+chagrin%2Cmea+culpa&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cto%20my%20shame%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bto%20my%20shame%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTo%20my%20shame%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cto%20my%20chagrin%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bto%20my%20chagrin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTo%20my%20chagrin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmea%20culpa%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmea%20culpa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMea%20culpa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMea%20Culpa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMEA%20CULPA%3B%2Cc0) shows that "To my chagrin" was (until recently) a little more popular then "To my shame". However both are currently behind the Latin phrase [*mea culpa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mea_culpa) which means "Through my fault".

Comment: Being unable to upvote all these great answers is very frustrating.

Comment: It's important to notice that *chagrin* does not confer any responsibility to the speaker, whereas *shame* does. I think the OP is looking for a term which specifically implicates his misdoing.

Comment: @Dan *Mea culpa*!

Comment: @Drake Looks like that isn't a problem any more!

Comment: In context -- "To my chagrin, I [did x]" -- it should be clear that they are taking responsibility. Anyway, I think this fits far better than "shame" (for the reasons given by commenters).

Comment: According to this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+my+shame%2Cto+my+chagrin%2Cto+my+discredit&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1) *to my shame* has recently overtaken *to my chagrin*.

Comment: I reiterate, [mea culpa (Ngram)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+my+shame%2Cto+my+chagrin%2Cmea+culpa&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cto%20my%20shame%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bto%20my%20shame%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20my%20Shame%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTo%20my%20shame%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cto%20my%20chagrin%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bto%20my%20chagrin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTo%20my%20chagrin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmea%20culpa%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmea%20culpa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMea%20culpa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMea%20Culpa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMEA%20CULPA%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I'm sorry but both our Ngram links demonstrate that [*to my shame*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+my+shame%2Cto+my+chagrin&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&) has overtaken *to my chagrin* and yet in your post you claim the opposite. Your Ngram is at fault because you spelt **To** *my shame* beginning with a capital letter, whereas *to my chagrin* is typed in lowercase. letters.

Comment: "to my chagrin" has an entirely different meaning to "to my shame". Elliot Frisch agrees. As a consequence, Ngrams and discussion are pointless.

Comment: @Greybeard I realize a good question is timeless, but it's been eight years.

Answer (score 14):

"To my detriment".

Full Definition of DETRIMENT
1
:  injury, damage  
2
:  a cause of injury or damage  
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detriment

Comment: Of all the suggestions here, "to my detriment" is definitely the one I'd be most likely to use. (Native BrE speaker)

Comment: Same here (Native AmE speaker)

Answer (score 3):

Popular with young people right now is:
My Bad
as in:
My bad; I did foo, bar, and baz,"

If you you're working with software engineers, you might want to keep you writing young and hip.  There's no room for old software engineers as I'm finding out :)

"There are old programmers, and there are bold programmers, but there are no old, bold programmers".  Blatantly plagiarized from Chuck Yeager.

Comment: Yes, it's popular but it is also *awful*.

Comment: @Dave regarding older programmers, please see  http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/06/20/MyLawn.html  Perhaps whoever's hiring the young and hip "software engineers" needs to see whether it's worth it. - Your fellow "older" programmer

Comment: DaveBoltman,  Thanks for the link. A good read.  Perhaps there is hope for me yet :)